# Monte Carlo Integration - Metropolis Algorithm using MATLAB

Tags: definite-integrals, matlab, monte-carlo

I want to compute the integral
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-\frac{1}{2} x^2} dx = \sqrt{2\pi} \approx 
 2.5066$$
using the Monte Carlo method by sampling $N$ points $\{x_i\}$ according to the normal distribution $e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. An approximation of the integral is
$$ I \approx \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i^2$$

I want to compute it with MATLAB. Here is my code:

```
targ = @(x) exp(-0.5*x^2);
proprnd = @(x) x+0.5 - 1.7*rand;
start = -0.1;
nsample = 10000;
for_sample()
histfit(x);
u = x.^2;
I = sum(u)/nsample

acc =

    0.5148


I =

    6.5270
```

Here, `for_sample` calls a .m file to create the sample points and here is its histogram, and `acc` is the acceptance rate of the points.  [image]

However, you can see that the result is not $I$ but a rough approximation of $I^2$. I do not know what is wrong! So I appreciate any help from you.

**Update**
As mentioned, There were two mistakes, one of them is taking into account the normalization constant, and the other is that my sample does not have a zero mean. Besides putting the normalization constant, I tried to change my `proprnd` function to be `x+0.5 - rand` and it works. I don't know why?! the `for_sample()` function should refuse any point outside the target pdf. Can anyone see where the mistake in the following code? Also, the result is not that good; it varies from 2.4 to 2.66.

```
x = [start];
count = 0;
for i = [1:1:nsample-1];
    xt = proprnd(x(i)) ;
    targ_old = targ(x(i));
    targ_new = targ(xt);
    r = targ_new / targ_old;
    if r > rand;
        x(i+1) = xt;
        count = count + 1;
    else
        x(i+1) = x(i);
    end
end
acc = count / nsample
```

Comment: Your histogram doesn't look like it has mean $0$... Are you sure you're sampling with the right distribution?

Comment: I would use `randn` for normally distributed numbers.

Comment: Also call them like you would functions. It is sloppy to omit the (). Maybe the reader thinks it's a variable and not a function call with 0 arguments.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I didn't notice that. I get a zero mean distribution when I modified the proposal point `proprnd` to be `x+0.5 - rand` and the result is better. However, I didn't understand why this happens as my code should refuse any point outside the target pdf. I will Edit my question so that I put the code for `for_sample` function. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I am learning to sample with the Metropolis algorithm.

Comment: @mathreadler I see your point, and I will use it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to approximate

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2 \exp\Big( -\frac{1}{2}x^2 \Big) \, dx $$

rewrite it as an expectation: $I = \mathbb{E}\big[ f(X) \big]$, where $f$ is some real-valued function and $X$ a random variable whose probability distribution is defined by some density function. Here, take :

$$ f(t) = \sqrt{2\pi} t^2 $$

and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. As a consequence :

$$ \mathbb{E}\big[ f(X) \big] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \varphi(t) \, dt $$

where $\varphi(t) = (\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1} \exp\big( -(1/2)t^2 \big)$ is the density function of the Gaussian distribution with zero mean and unit variance.

Results on Monte Carlo integration state that if $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ are independent samples from the $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ distribution, then :

$$ \lim \limits_{N \to +\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(X_i) = \mathbb{E}[ f(X) \big]. $$

In practice, take $N$ large ($N=10^5$, for example). To obtain the samples $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ use the `randn` function, as suggested in a comment. The Metropolis-Hastings algorithm is not needed here. One may want to use this algorithm when the density of the random variable $X$ is known only **up to a normalizing constant** (which, for some reason, is not tractable).

** Complement ** : By the way, there is no need for an histogram here. This won't give you information about the quality of you approximation. Instead, plot

$$ \hat{I}(N) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f(X_i) $$

as a function of the integer $N$. You may use the function `quad` to obtain a *reliable* approximation of $I$. Then, as $N$ goes to infinity, you'll observe that the values of $\hat{I}(N)$ come closer and closer to this value you obtained with the `quad` function.

Comment: I am learning to sample with the Metropolis algorithm. I have plotted the histogram to ensure that the sample is correct then the result must be correct. However, there are two mistakes; one of them is taking into account the normalization constant as you state, and the other is that my sample does not have a zero mean as stated in a comment. I did not know why the `proprnd` function affect the sample. I will appreciate your help in my code for sampling.

Comment: @AhmedElashry : In the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, the probability density used as **proposal distribution** has a strong impact on the behavior of the algorithm. If there is a problem with you `proprnd`, it's no mystery why you're not sampling from the right distribution. More over, consider including a burn-in period (discard the $N$ first samples).

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know what do you mean by the probability density used as proposal distribution and its impact. Also, I do not know the problem with my `proprnd`. the code of `for_sample()` is supposed to work with any `proprnd` function. Isn't it?

Comment: @AhmedElashry : A Metropolis-Hastings algorithm aims at creating an ergodic Markov chain $(X_n)_n$ whose stationary distribution is your target distribution. At each iteration, either the chain stays in its current state or it moves to another state. The way it moves and where is given by the **proposal distribution**. It plays a key role in the algorithm. If you've never heard about it, I strongly suggest you read about the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm before trying to implement it.

Comment: I was reading about Metropolis not Metropolis-Hastings so there wasn't any mention for a pdf of the proposal distribution. I understand your comments now. The mistake in my first code was that the pdf of the proposal distribution is not symmetric and I should have taken it into account as you said in your first comment. Thank you very much for your help.